# Async task resets my spinner

Tags: android, asynchronous, spinner

newbie here.
Before posting code, a simple description.

1. I have a small app which loads data from via http, stores it in an SQL Lite database, and displays it - setting up two spinners, one with names and one with a day of the week. Selecting a combination for name and day of the week shows text indicating what that person is doing on that day. When the combination is selection, it is saved using SharedPreferences. All this works fine.
2. I set up an async task under a 'refresh' button, to go and fetch new data from the server. This goes away and gets the data, repopulates the database, and refreshes the display. Most of this works fine, except that the name spinner is always reset to the first entry, as if it's being re-initialised somehow.
3. On debugging this, all works well, until the async tasks ends up in the Looper class. I'm not sure what this does, but looks like some cleaning up, and somewhere in there, the spinner is reset.
4. Below is the async task, stripped down.

Any ideas?

```
private class GetDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String response = "";
ProgressBar pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinner1 );

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pb.setMax(100);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... mystring) {
        //get database
       response=get_data_from_PMS();
       Load_Arrays_with_stored_data();
       return response;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // display new updated consultant list
        ArrayAdapter adapter_cons = new ArrayAdapter(whereisthatconsultantActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cons_spinner);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter_cons);
        adapter_cons.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //
       spinner1.setSelection(GetDisplayVal("selconspos"));

    //
    textView2.setText(display_stored_data());
    //
    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
}
```

Comment: So, it's a spinner. Which means ProgressBar that's circular right? It doesn't actually show linear progress, it's just a spinning circle that means 'hold up a sec'. So when you say resetting, what do you mean? I have a program that uses a spinner while it completes an AsyncTask, so I just want to make sure I understand the problem before I respond.

Comment: @Davek804: No, an Android `Spinner` is basically a drop-down list. Never worked out why they named it 'Spinner'.

Comment: Good thing I didn't put out a whole response and make myself look like an idiot! Hopefully someone else can solve this issue :)

Comment: So, what is your 'name' spinner; `spinner1`? Since you're (re)setting the adapter in the `onPostExecute` of your AsyncTask (why?), I'm assuming that `setSelection(...)` is supposed to reselect the earlier selected position in the Spinner? Did you verify `GetDisplayVal(...)` actually returns the correct value?

Comment: Something tells me after u refresh the data, this method GetDisplayVal("selconspos") does not return back a valid position. Just print the value and check.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would do it for you but it may have something to do with the fact that your creating a new adapter every time onPostExecute is being executed.  Can you remove the following lines from the onPostExecute to somewhere else(maybe onCreate):

```
ArrayAdapter adapter_cons = new ArrayAdapter(whereisthatconsultantActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cons_spinner);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter_cons);
adapter_cons.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Then change your onPostExecute to something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

   adapter_cons.notifyDataSetChanged();
   spinner1.setSelection(GetDisplayVal("selconspos"));
   textView2.setText(display_stored_data());
   pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
```

That should update your adapter assuming, because I'm having a hard time determining from the code, that your assigning new data to your adapter in the doInBackground().  Each time you update the data in the adapter you must call notifyDataSetChanged() to get the adapter to update.

Hope that helps!